# how to add a xml node to xml DataColumn and return Xml Datacolumn as string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below. ID column should be added into XML tag as Value with respective ID Column value and return as one XML tag

```
 Ex:
Specification                | ID
<car><Name>BMW</Name></car>  | 245
<car><Name>Audi</Name></car> | 290
<car><Name>Skoda</Name></car>| 295
```

Output Should be as

```
|  Specification    |
| <car><Name>BMW</Name><ID>245</ID></car><car><Name>Audi</Name><ID>290</ID></car><car><Name>Audi</Name><ID>295</ID></car> |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `modify()` and `insert` xml like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Specification xml,
    Id int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES 
('<car><Name>BMW</Name></car>', 245),
('<car><Name>Audi</Name></car>', 290),
('<car><Name>Skoda</Name></car>', 295)


Update @SampleData SET  Specification.modify('insert <Id>{sql:column("sd.Id")}</Id> into (/car)[1]') 
FROM @SampleData sd

SELECT sd.* FROM @SampleData sd
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/HHPJW51723)

Some reference links:
   [modify xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type) 
   [insert xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/insert-xml-dml)

Comment: @MaheshAkula A tiny hint: It's always a good idea to specify the place, where to insert (`as last/first` and `after/before`). +1 from my side

Answer (score 0):

this is one way I can think of. You can strip the value of the car name using the [.node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type), and reconstruct the XML. Something like,

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Specification    XML,
    ID               INT
)

INSERT #Temp ( Specification, ID )
VALUES
('<car><Name>BMW</Name></car>', 245),
('<car><Name>Audi</Name></car>', 290),
('<car><Name>Skoda</Name></car>', 295)

SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        Val.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') AS Name,
        T.ID 
    FROM #Temp AS T
    CROSS APPLY Specification.nodes('car/Name') AS Id(Val)
) X
FOR XML PATH('Name'), ROOT ('Car')

DROP TABLE #Temp
```